# Can a win phone 8 app run on win surface rt?

Tags: windows-phone-8, windows-runtime, windows-rt

If not then what all modifications would be needed for the same. I have an app written for Windows Phone 8 and have to port it for Windows Surface RT. What all are the key points to look for and if possible any documentations pointing to the same.

Comment: see also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7429283/how-easy-is-it-to-port-a-windows-phone-7-application-to-metro-on-a-windows-8-tab

Answer (score 3):

No, you can not directly port. If you have used MVVM pattern then you can reuse you MODEL and VIEMODEL. You have to modify VIEW only. For more information on MVVM you can look at the [MSDN Documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/gg521153%28v=vs.105%29.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

No Windows Phone apps cannot run directly on any other device other than windows phone.

That said, MOST of the code can be reused.

Look into Portable class libraries (PCL).

These libraries allow you to write code that is reusable across multiple platforms.

PCL's -
[MSDN Document on Portable Class Libraries](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/gg597391%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)

Comment: Can you suggest on what all libraries might be required to be ported for the Windows RT platform. Also the link you gave are not pointing to the windows 8 and rt supports, is there some other place we need to look for that resource?

Comment: You write your own libraries